# Laravel Upload Multiple Images Each With Different User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to upload multiple images, each associated with different employees. Here is an example scenario. I have 4 employees. I want to add different image for 2 of the employees and nothing for rest 2. Here is what happens now:

1. If I add no image for any one, all 4 gets the default image (which is expected)
2. If I add different image for 2 employees and leave other 2, all 4 gets last uploaded image.
3. If I add one image for 1 employee, and leave other 3, all 4 gets the uploaded image.

For 2 and 3 situations, I expect to upload associated image for each employee and default image if not uploaded.

Here is the form:

```
@if ($employee->payment_option == 2)
   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('receipt') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
   <input type="file" name="receipt[]" multiple>
       @if ($errors->has('receipt'))
           <span class="help-block">
               <strong>{{ $errors->first('receipt') }}</strong>
           </span>
       @endif
   </div>
@endif
```

Here is the controller store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('receipt')) {
            $files = $request->file('receipt');
            foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $fileName = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $folderpath  = 'public/images'.'/';
                $file->move($folderpath, $fileName);
            }
        }

        foreach ($request->employee_id as $key => $val) {
            $payrolls = new Payroll;
            $payrolls->employee_id = $val;
            if (!empty($request->receipt)) {
                $payrolls->receipt = $fileName;
            } else {
                $payrolls->receipt = 'noimage.jpg';
            }
            $payrolls->save();
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

There are several questions to upload multiple files and their solutions are good. However I need to upload each file associated with each employee. And if file is not uploaded for an employee, the default image should be attached with it.

Comment: try to use `uniqid()` or `microtime()` insted of `time()`.

Comment: Thank you. However that is not the problem. This is just for naming the file. Nothing to do with image upload.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="receipt[]" multiple>
```

i think you are using same name `receipt` for all forms ... use different names like "`receipt1`, `receipt2`" ...like that and change controller accordingly .

Comment: I want to use only one form to upload all. Uploading individually is not a problem.